How to Read Compressed Data from Azure Event Hub in Fabric using Py-spark
I am sending compressed data into Event Hub to overcome 1 MB hard limit in Azure Event Hub.
I also have to read this in Py-spark and update delta table.
The compressed data send to Event hub is coming  as null in Py-spark stream. How to read it?
This is how I am reading from Event Hub
 df_stream_body = df_stream.select(F.from_json(F.col("body").cast("string"), message_schema).alias("Payload"))

This is how I am sending data to Event Hub .
event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()
    # Add events to the batch.
    body = '{"id": "90", "firstName": "Sudarshan70","middleName": "Kumar2","lastName": "Thakur2"}'  
    
    # Compress the JSON string using the gzip algorithm.
    compressed_body = gzip.compress(body.encode('utf-8'))

    # Encode the compressed JSON string to base64.
    encoded_compressed_body = base64.b64encode(compressed_body)
    

    event_data_batch.add(EventData(encoded_compressed_body))

I tried to read with option as gzip but its giving me null .
df_stream  = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs")\
  .options(**ehConf)\
  .option("compression", "gzip") \
  .load() 

And this is how I read body column
def foreach_batch_function(df_stream, epoch_id):
              # temp_view_name = "stream_temp"
              df_stream_body = df_stream.select(F.from_json(F.col("body").cast("string"), message_schema).alias("Payload"))
              df_stream_body.createOrReplaceTempView("stream_temp")
              # df_stream_body.printSchema()


How you are sending compressed data to eventhub. give sample data.

can you check this once?

this exactly what i need @Bhavani and i have used gzip in the option but in delta table values goes as null for all columns

You need to do decompress on the column body, the option .option("compression", "gzip") is for compressed files not on compressed data on the column.
So, need to create user defined function which decompress and decodes the data.
Use below code.
UDF
import  pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import gzip,base64,json


def unZip(binary_string):
    return gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(binary_string)).decode('utf-8')

unzip = F.udf(unZip, StringType())

Next, create new column with decompressed data.
df.withColumn("bd", unzip(F.col("body").cast('string'))).display()

Output:


I have updated my question .Can you please help in how we can combine your DF with mine

I have modified as below `def unZip(binary_string):
return gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(binary_string)).decode('utf-8')
unzip = F.udf(unZip, StringType())
def foreach_batch_function(df_stream, epoch_id):
# temp_view_name = "stream_temp"
df_stream_body = df_stream.select(F.from_json(unzip(F.col("body").cast("string")), message_schema).alias("Payload"))` still coming as null

May be  the schema provided is wrong. are you getting results from unzip functions correctly as string?
